# Remove keyboard shortcuts of the Dock's applications (Gnome 3.26.2, Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: shortcuts, gnome-shell, dock, ubuntu-dock

When hitting Win+1, the first application of the dock is launched. Same for Win+2 to second application, etc.

Is it possible to disable this feature?
(personally, it interferes with my desktop selection shortcuts)

Comment: Even though this question is a duplicate, it helped me to navigate to other question! Uses better words for google search,...